# Fade out multiple Bootstrap alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I came across a question asking how to fade out Bootstrap alerts after 5 seconds, and the answer was the following code. The issue is, it only works once, however as I have multiple alerts that are generated after an AJAX call this is no good. How do I make the following code run every time an alert is triggered?

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
     $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
          $(this).remove(); 
     });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Show the code where "alerts are generated after an AJAX call", that's where you'll want to put the code to hide them.

Answer (score 6):

One possible solution is to use a custom event `showalert` after the alert is shown and in the event handler remove the alert

```
$(document).on('showalert', '.alert', function(){
    window.setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
            $(this).remove(); 
        });
    }, this), 5000);
})
```

and

```
$('<div class="alert alert-error">' + 'some message' + '</div>').appendTo('#result').trigger('showalert');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UZUb4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because `$(this).remove();` removes the alert from the DOM. You can actually just modify the content without regenerating the alert every time after the AJAX call.